# Polygon fitting along the line keeping its area using ArcGIS Desktop (ArcPy)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, polygon, buffer

I have a layer with polygons. And I need them to fit along the line. With Reshape Feature Tool I can do this, but there is one problem, the polygon area changes. 
I need to keep the polygon area. Any idea how to do this?

[image]

Comment: Please add some kind of code attempt or your question will likely be closed

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a Little bit unclear (you want the polygon side to align perfectly with the line, for example change the shape of polygon 2?) and can very likely be solved using Snap geoprocessing tool etc. But anyway in the very specific case you show in your screenshot, this could work:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\somefolder\Default.gdb'
lines = 'snapline'
polygons = 'areas'
polycopy = 'areas2' #To not mess with original data

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(in_features=polygons, out_feature_class=polycopy)

theline = [i[0] for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(lines,'SHAPE@')][0]

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(polycopy, ['SHAPE@', 'SHAPE@X']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0].crosses(theline):
            extents = [c.extent for c in row[0].cut(theline)] #Create extents (rectangular bounding boxes) for the two polygon halves split by the line
            xmax = sorted([c.XMax for c in extents])[1] #Find the rightmost x coordinate of the right polygon half
            xmin = sorted([c.XMin for c in extents])[1] #Find the leftmost x coordinate of the right half
            row[1] = row[1]+(xmin-xmax) #Move entire polygon to the left by the difference
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

[image]